# convert using ffmpeg without exec

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have Windows XP, Apache, PHP 5.3 and ffmpeg working fine. I need to convert flv to avi or vice versa without using the `exec()` command. Is this possible?

Thank you.

edit : 
i hope someone could edit the ffmpeg source and implement an exec function into the php extension so we could just add the parameters to a function (ex $fmpeg->exec('exec parameters here'); ) so the exec is executed directly from the extension ...

and compile those file :p

Comment: Not really an answer so I will post here: a custom made PHP extension that will do what you need could be the solution

Comment: any programming experience?(desktop not web)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, at least there seems no example where `ffmpeg` runs without some type of system call (e.g. `exec`, `system`) from PHP.

Edit: One option is using the dreaded `safe_mode`. Refer to the [manual on `exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you
>   can only execute files within the
>   safe_mode_exec_dir. ...

In theory you can place the ffmpeg binary in an arbitrary directory and give the path of that directory to the `safe_mode_exec_dir`. That way users will only be able to run executables in that directory. But you must try and see the implications of such a setup in real life...

Regarding your PHP extension request: PHP ffmpeg extension is just an informational one. If you need one that can do things on actual files, you will need to build a new extension based on `ffmpeg` library.

And if you plan to do this on a shared hosting, you are most probably out of luck. A standard issue shared hosting provider wouldn't provide video functionality like this. Video hosting and processing requires specialized hosting at best.

Comment: i have my dedicated servers , and i want my customers to be able to use ffmpeg , without the need to enable the exec or system functions :)

Comment: well , i have windows servers as well , doupt it will work on that !?

Comment: It seems so. See a comment at the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php#40870

Answer (score 3):

There is a version of ffmpeg for PHP:

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have ffmpeg installed as an extension for PHP already , its just that the documentation says nothing about converting , only getting stuff , my clients are banned from using the exec command , so i need a method to convert videos directly from php without using exec within the code .

Comment: As ffmpeg is a compiled binary, there is no way (using ffmpeg) to manipulate files without using `exec`. Every tutorial uses `exec`: http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

Comment: Also, why are your clients "banned" from using `exec`?

Comment: Probably shared hosting. Your clients shouldn't even THINK about doing movie recoding on shared hosting boxes. That's just plain rude towards other customers on the server as recoding needs lots of computing power.

Comment: Not only is it rude, but it's virtually guaranteed to have their accounts cancelled.

Comment: I am the provider of the shared host , each server has 2 clients , i don't want them to use exec , but i want the to use ffmpeg :) .

Comment: @Evan Mulawski, It was my understanding that if you build FFMPEG yourself, then you didn't have to worry about copyright/patent issues with the codecs.  The trouble occurs with distributing the binaries.  Is this not the case?  Or were you referring to possible use of FFMPEG for encoding copyrighted material... which I assure you is a separate issue.

Comment: @Brad: I was referring to the encoding/decoding of copyrighted material and how it may be distributed.

Comment: it's not a copyrighted material , i have a news site , i want writers to be able to upload thier OWN videos that they recorded using mobile phones (3gp) or cameras (mp4 and other) then those videos to be converted to flv and displayed on the site using a flash vid player . my customers (2) are on one server that i run , i don't want them to use the exec to hack each other ... thats all :)

Comment: @Ronan on a machine with properly set up permissions, allowing `exec()` shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use exec() on the webserver for security reasons and the videos don't have to be converted in "realtime", you could use a unix-like cronjob for windows, create a php-script and use the php-interpreter.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/bring-linux-cron-like-power-to-windows/ or
http://www.visualcron.com/

a) A user uploads a video and this video is saved to a temporary path. The video gets an id and a timestamp, which are saved to a database.

b) Every 15 minutes, a webserver independant php script, jar-file or c#-executable is called to create the ffmpeg comand and the necessary parameters. Then the file is converted, moved to a 'converted'-folder, the original file is deleted or moved to an 'archive'-folder and the database is updated.

Answer (score 1):

> http://ffencoderd.sourceforge.net/index.html
>
> Using a job queue and an XML based
>   communication, videos can be sent so
>   they're encoded.

Sounds like a plan to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to exec somewhere. If you can not do it on your host computer another solution is to have another system download convert and then upload the converted video and repeat. A more idea solution would be post to another online account convert and download. Between those options the first would be scalable.

Neither of these solutions are off the shelf that I know about. They would need to be created.

I believe the reason the format is not processed in an open PHP or Perl is because of potential licensing issues. FLV is not an open source format. So the perl and php frameworks make a exec request to process the video using ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to utilize Suhosin. You could then at least limit where exactly the system call can from and in turn limit access to that directory.

Here's an basic example of a vhost.conf config where shell_exec is blocked everywhere in your domain except ffmpeg-folder utilizing Suhosin

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName your.server
DocumentRoot "/var/your/public_html"
php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "shell_exec, passthru, show_source, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_terminate, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, escapeshellcmd, escapeshellarg, exec"

<Directory "/var/your/public_html/ffmpeg-folder">
php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist "passthru, show_source, system, pcntl_exec, popen, pclose, proc_open, proc_nice, proc_terminate, proc_get_status, proc_close, leak, apache_child_terminate, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, escapeshellcmd, escapeshellarg, exec"
</Directory>
</virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pclose(popen($cmd, 'r'));` instead exec()

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can connect to ssh in php and execute commands there.