# php library for ffmpeg video processing?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg on my server.

Now I am looking for a php library which can perform ffmpeg functionality, like retrieving video information, converting it to FLV or in any other format, and streaming video.

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: I think there are PHP wrappers to ffmpeg, but there always also is the possibility of calling it directly through `exec()`

Comment: @pekka is right, if you going to use a wrapper, only use a wrapper for executing commands through exec

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert using ffmpeg without exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173405/convert-using-ffmpeg-without-exec) and 100 similar questions tagged [php+ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+ffmpeg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below function to convert mp4 video to flv

```
function mp4toflv($in, $out)
{
    //echo $in.'  '.$out;
    $thumb_stdout;
    $errors;
    $retval = 0;


    // Delete the file if it already exists
    if (file_exists($out)) { unlink($out); }
    $cmd  = "ffmpeg -i $in -ar 22050 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32K -r 25 -s 320x240 -vcodec flv $out";

    //$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $in -b 1024k -s 352x264 -r 25 -acodec copy $out";
    //echo escapeshellcmd($cmd);
        exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd));
    unlink($in); 

}
```

similarly you can also convert other video formats to flv or any other format. Below are some help to convert videos to mp4(h264)

```
1]. ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
2]. ffmpeg input.AVI -vcodec libx264 -sameq output.mp4
```

option 1 can use for :- (mp4,mov,flv)
option 2 can user for :- (3gp,avi,mp4,mov,flv)

execute above commands using "exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd))" where $cmd will be any from above two options.

Hope this will help someone :)

Comment: Do you mean option 2 can have input of all these files (3gp,avi,mp4,mov,flv) and it will convert to mp4?

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) without any major problems, just make sure you are using supported ffmpeg version. If you need any special behaviour, you can always additionally wrap it using `exec()`.